# Broken pipe, write error: An epidemic of unnecessary output

Tags: command-line, bash, unix, pipe, gnu

In the last few months, a problem has been spreading across my systems. That of broken pipe errors:

```sh
# Solution:
# silenced by replacing /bin/bzip2 -> bzip2-reference
#                    to /bin/bzip2 -> lbzip2
$ man man
#err# bzip2: I/O or other error, bailing out.  Possible reason follows.
#err# bzip2: Broken pipe
#err#   Input file = (stdin), output file = (stdout)
#err#
#err# bzip2: I/O or other error, bailing out.  Possible reason follows.
#err# bzip2: Broken pipe
#err#   Input file = (stdin), output file = (stdout)

# Solution: 
# silenced by using awk: find -type f -name '*.pdf' | awk 'NR==1'
find -type f -name '*.pdf' | head -1
#err# find: ‘standard output’: Broken pipe
#err# find: write error

# I don't know how to silence the rest of these
tar tvf archive.tar | head
#err# tar: stdout: write error

sed $'s/\t/\t-\t/' table.tsv | head | column -ts $'\t' -R 1;
#err# sed: couldn't write 42 items to stdout: Broken pipe
```

Installed packages:

```yaml
# distro: gentoo
app-shells/bash-5.1_p16-r6:  /usr/bin/bash
app-arch/tar-1.35:           /usr/bin/gtar
sys-apps/findutils-4.9.0-r2: /usr/bin/gfind
sys-apps/sed-4.9:            /usr/bin/gsed
sys-libs/glibc-2.38-r10:
sys-apps/coreutils-9.4:
sys-apps/systemd-255.3-r1:
```

Additional system info:

```sh
grep ^Sig /proc/self/status
#out# SigQ: 3/256943
#out# SigPnd:0000000000000000
#out# SigBlk:0000000000000000
#out# SigIgn:0000000000001000
#out# SigCgt:0000000000000400

# Login via vt1 (virtual terminal), then invoke startx for display server
```

I'd imagine goodfellows here are aware of [Unix Philosophy: "Avoid unnecessary output"](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Unix_philosophy#Eric_Raymond%27s_17_Unix_Rules) rule. Considering a 90% of computer use happens from a terminal, this spam is highly undesired.

I'm trying to think of solutions:

1. Replace implementations, <s>`bzip2-reference`</s> to `lbzip2`.
2. Replace usage, <s>`head`</s> to `awk 'NR<11'`.

   - I'm in a disagreement, breaking the pipe sounds like a reasonable thing to do. What if the stdin is GiB? TiB? infinite? curl? serial?
3. Add `2>/dev/null` to every pipeline command. You know why this is a bad idea.
4. Downgrade packages. I can't do that anymore. I want to be up-to-date anyway.
5. Add patches to `/etc/portage/patches/`. This sounds like the most reasonable solution, which is unreasonable.

Further, this seems to render `man man` to be broken, `head` to be broken, the entire convention of piping text to be broken.

What happened? I feel like I'm out of the loop on what happened. Someone must be in-the-loop. So I'd appreciate recent references to some viral nuclear meltdown due broken pipes that triggered this cascade of spams to be implemented, if that's what it is.

Maybe there's some simple file I need to edit in `/etc/` to disable this policy system-wide. Maybe It's a GNU issue, and the solution is to migrate away from GNU stack. Maybe there's some ENV variable I can set in `/etc/profile`. Maybe there's a compile-time flag I need to apply. There's got to be.

Comment: What's the output of `grep ^Sig /proc/self/status` and How do you log in to the system? What's the entire chain from "which init system do you use" to "which login manager do you type your password into" to "which shell do you use"?

Comment: @u1686_grawity, I've revised post to include additional info.

Comment: "spreading" - is that related to some update that's done automatically?

Comment: @harrymc, "spreading", as in, first noticed with `man` months ago, then with `find`, `tar`, `sed` over the course of time. I'd suspect systemd, issue is it happens on my openrc laptop too. Thus suspicion of package updates.

Comment: Package updates would be my first suspicion too, but only you can find that out.

Answer (score 0):

The programs haven't changed. They've always been outputting messages upon encountering a write error, and "Broken pipe" (-EPIPE) has always been the error code returned to the writer in case the reader exits early.

Except, usually, the kernel *kills the process* that would be receiving the error code (by issuing SIGPIPE) so that it never gets a chance to output an error message.

Killing the process is what you generally want in shell pipelines, but not what you want for services – if a service can be made to open a file, that's usually not good in itself, but if it can be made to open a pipe that you then close, the entire service dies.

So if you're starting any relevant part of your X11 session through 'systemd --user' services (e.g. if you have a .service for your terminal emulator or a .service for the entire window manager), the service manager will add SIGPIPE to the *ignored signals set* before starting the process and you have to add `IgnoreSIGPIPE=no` to opt out of that.

Otherwise, go through your process tree until you find the highest process that is involved and has the SIGPIPE bit set in `SigIgn:` in its /proc/PID/status; either that or its parent will be the cause.